# Randomised rows & specific row

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if it is possible to get a random array of ID's from a table but include one in particular?

So say I have 200 rows, I might limit my script to output 20 but one of the rows must include id 2 (for example).

Not sure if this is possible, would appreciate any help received.

Comment: so pick row with id=2 and 19 random rows....

Comment: Yes, the specific id will change each time - but I can work out which id that is. However it's including this id with a bunch of random rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, if(id = 2, -1, rand()) as sort from my_table order by sort limit 20
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, I created an array with the results, shuffled the array and then used this in a seperate query to give me the results I needed :D

Answer (score 0):

Not the final solution, but maybe this thread helps you:

[MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

By the way: I'd handle the randomstuff within the script (e.g. PHP) with cached (e.g. Memcached) datasets. But that depends on your goal.